# Passing $scope.variable from view to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a basic ionic app which allows as user to enter their first name and last name, beneath those two fields is a button which says next.

On click the user is passed to the terms page where they are shown are shown text on a screen, after click accept terms button I fire an ngResource query to post the data to the server.

My form works great without a terms screen if the submit button is on the first page but on the second it's almost like the postData is refreshed and the data wipes.

**See my code:**

**First Form Page (State = enterdetails)**

```
    <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="postData.first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">

    <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="postData.last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">

    <button class="button button-cv button-large button-block" style="margin-bottom:20px" ng-click="terms()">Next</button>
```

**Second Page with Terms (State = terms)**

```
TERMS TEXT
<button class="button button-cv button-large button-block" ng-click="newPost()">Accept & Sign Up</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('memberCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, Post, $window) {

            $scope.postData = {}; //object to collect the data to post
            $scope.postData.first_name = '';
            $scope.postData.last_name = '';

            $scope.terms = function(){
                $state.go('terms');
            }

            $scope.newPost = function() {

                var post = new Post($scope.postData);
                post.$save(); // postData posted to server and saved.

                $state.go('enterdetails'); // after submit go back to main screen again
            }
})
```

Is there any reason why the postdata doesn't stick when moving to the terms page? like i said if I just put the newPost() on the first page this works fine its when the user has to accept the terms.

Comment: each time a controller is instanciated, $scope is inherited from $rootScope. When you change the URL of the page, you loose your $scope. To still have the values, in $scope.terms you can do $rootScope.postData = $scope.postData; and you will have $scope.postData available in the new controller. When the process ends, you will have to remove $rootScope.postData to clean it. $rootScope is the only one scope available in all the controllers, and is never erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up routing (with `ui-router` for ionic), you create a template and a controller for each state. This means that when you use `$state.go()`, the template is changed, and a new controller is instantiated.

For every controller created, a new `$scope` is also created for that particular controller. So while you are on the `member` page, `$scope.postData` exists, and is usable. However, when you transition to the `terms` state, that controller is discarded, and a new one is used (destroying your post data).

What you want to do is create something like a service to manage data that you want to persist between state changes. For example:

```
.service('UserService', function(){
    var user = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: ''
    };

    this.getUser = function(){
        return user;
    };
});
```

Then you simply need to inject this service into both your controllers, and edit the object returned by `UserService.getUser();`. Once you are ready to post, use the same object to create your resource.

Comment: Thanks for that, quick question - from the first page after injecting the service into the controller how would I bind the inputs to the service user?

Comment: `$scope.postData = UserService.getUser();` - That should work, but hopefully you get the idea if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks pal, i've not used services before.. just thinking about the above - would this work for new information too? i.e. When the user enters first name this populates the service.user.first_name? sorry for the confusion

Comment: so I just included `first_name` etc for brevity. Really the user object could simply be blank `{}`. And you can use any names in your model. Sorry I probably should have been specific about that.

Comment: That's brilliant! just tested and it seems to be exactly what I'm after - nice one. Just out of interest before I have to write another question! is there a way to reset the userservice?

Comment: Just think of a service as a module you can do anything you want to, and have any interface functions you want. So you could have `this.reset = function(){ ... }`, which does something to the user object. Any of the service functions that start with `this` are callable by controllers, while without `this` become private functions to the service (only callable from inside).